# Are these two events independent?

Tags: probability, permutations

`Let n ≥ 3 be an integer, consider a uniformly random permutation of the set
{1, 2, . . . , n}, and define the events`

`A = “in this permutation, 2 is to the left of 3”`

`and`

`B = “in this permutation, 1 is to the left of 2 and 1 is to the left of 3”.`

`Are these two events independent? Justify your answer.
Hint: Use the Product Rule to count the number of permutations that define A and B`

Not really sure how do justify this. Looking at it logically it seems to be that they are not independent because B is basically saying 1 & 2 are always to the left of 3, and if B is an event, then 2 is guaranteed to be to the left of 3, which is what A is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "B is basically saying 1 & 2 are always to the left of 3" What? Why do you think B is saying that?

Answer (score 3):

No, they're independent. By some symmetry principles you only need to count the permutations of the set $\{1,2,3\}$; these 6 permutations are:

```
                 2 then 3 |  3 then 2
1 before both      123    |    132
--------------------------+------------
1 not before       213    |    312
                   231    |    321
```

As you can see from the nice split in the graph, the independence is manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes intuition about independence is clear. But sometimes it is not, so let us calculate.

By symmetry $\Pr(A)=\frac{1}{2}$.

For $\Pr(B)$, note that there are $3!$ equally likely permutations of $1,2,3$ (since all permutations are equally likely, the location of the other numbers is irrelevant.)  We count the ones that satisfy $B$. They are $123$ and $132$. So $\Pr(B)=\frac{2}{6}$.

Finally, we calculate $\Pr(A\cap B)$. Only the permutation $123$ satisfies this.

Now we can check whether $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$.